# Wakeup from touchscreen does NOT work in embedded Linux

Tags: linux, touch, interrupt, power-management

I am working on an embedded Linux (kernel-5.10.24) and there is a GT911 based touchscreen.
The touchscreen is working well now.

Then I tried to test the suspend/resume in this system.
There is an RTC which is configured to wake up system in 120 seconds, and it also worked well, the touchscreen is also black in suspend and back to work after resume.

Currently, I want to wake up system with screen touching but failed.
I found the device tree does NOT enable slide-wake feature, so I changed the dts as follows,

```
goodix,slide-wakeup = <1>;
```

And I can see wakeup is enabled from kernel log.

```
goodix-ts 0-0004: slide-wakeup enabled
goodix-ts 0-0004: INT num 36, trigger type:2
goodix-ts 0-0004: slide wakeup enabled
```

I can see `/sys/class/wakeup/*` showed the name about gt9xx.

When I put system into suspend mode, I still cannot wake up system by touching the screen.

I am not very familiar with Linux suspend/resume architecture, I am wondering what is necessary to wake up system from a touchscreen.

The gt9xx code is from https://github.com/goodix/gt9xx_driver_android/blob/master/gt9xx.c

It has functions as follows,

```
static int gtp_wakeup_sleep(struct goodix_ts_data *ts)
{
    u8 retry = 0;
    int ret = -1;

    while (retry++ < 10) {
        gtp_int_output(ts, 1);
        usleep_range(5000, 6000);

        ret = gtp_i2c_test(ts->client);
        if (!ret) {
            dev_dbg(&ts->client->dev, "Success wakeup sleep\n");

            gtp_int_sync(ts, 25);
            if (ts->pdata->esd_protect)
                gtp_init_ext_watchdog(ts->client);

            return ret;
        }
        gtp_reset_guitar(ts->client, 20);
    }

    dev_err(&ts->client->dev, "Failed wakeup from sleep mode\n");
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

And in  `gtp_probe()`
it does followings to setup wakeup.

```
    gtp_work_control_enable(ts, false);
    if (ts->pdata->slide_wakeup) {
        dev_info(&client->dev, "slide wakeup enabled\n");
        ret = enable_irq_wake(client->irq);
        if (ret < 0)
            dev_err(&client->dev, "Failed set irq wake\n");
    }
```

To test the codes, I did followings,
`echo standby > /sys/power/state`.  The system is suspended.
I touched the screen (point and slide), to wake up system, but failed.
The system is woken up after 120 seconds by RTC alarm timer.

Comment: You are **using** a program, not writing one. This Q is more appropriate to [unix.se]. Please delete here and repost there. Good luck.

Comment: I don't like current style in SO, that says Q can be asked here should be about programing. I followed the rule and got further comment like this.  I don't know what should be asked here and what is the future of SO if it is NOT open and tolerant any more.

Comment: I also want to emphasize: I also wrote some codes even not ALL of the codes, to figure out how does it work. I am NOT only "using" a program.

Comment: I agree that this question is more about configuring and using your system. If you think that it is more related to programming, then I suggest to rephrase your question accordingly and show your code. Regarding your problem: (In a question asked on a better matching site) Add more details about your hardware, both your system and the touchscreen. Does the hardware support waking up the systems using the connections between touchscreen and computer? Is the touchscreen powered during suspend?

Comment: If you include a small test case of programming code, I'll gladly remove my close vote, but readers need code they can evaluate and experiment to be able to help. You seem to think someone has already figured this problem out and can say "fix line 434 in something.c". I think there is low probability of that happening. Read/reflect/act-upon [mcve] and you may figure out the problem by yourself. If not, then with some code, readers can help. Finally, I  agree with @Bodo 's comments, \use them as a further guide to improving your question. Good luck

Comment: I provided more details in original question. I could NOT provide more details on the hardware of system except for the touchscreen. Short answer to Bodo's comments, the code showed it supports wakeup, and the interrupts from touchscreen is working. I need to check if the screen is powered when system is suspended.

Comment: pluse-uno for adding your code. Good luck.